# is gazebo 1.2.5 unit-aware?

Tags: mesh

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I use a number of COLLADA meshes exported from Sketchup, which defaults to inches during the export. This has not been a problem in the past, as I simply scale all my models appropriately (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11013/importing-collada-meshes-into-a-gazebo-world/)).

I recently upgraded from ROS Fuerte to Groovy, and it seems that Gazebo 1.2.5 now takes into account that the meshes are in inches, whereas ROS continues to ignore it. An example mesh can be seen [here](http://cs.utexas.edu/%7Epiyushk/share/hokuyo.dae).

I've fixed all the units in my meshes to meters (a bit annoying to do in Sketchup), but it is good to know why the behavior changed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/581/is-gazebo-1.2.5-unit-aware?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/131/piyushk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 138 on 2013-01-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, Gazebo has become unit aware when importing collada meshes. We did this to enforce consistency in models.

Note: Some collada exporters, such as Blender, do not export units correctly.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1